# Inserting data into a table from another table and eliminating duplicates in certain columns

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table called HotelReviews and I want to populate another table called Hotels with data from HotelReviews.

These are some of the columns that HotelReviews has: hotel_id, price, rating, url, author, content... So an example input might be:

```
INSERT INTO HotelReviews(hotel_id, price, rating, url, author, content...) VALUES (65729, 100, 4, ''http://www.tripadvisor.com/...', 'rick76', 'I enjoyed my stay.'...);

INSERT INTO HotelReviews(hotel_id, price, rating, url, author, content...) VALUES (65729, 100, 4, ''http://www.tripadvisor.com/...', 'eve66', 'I enjoyed my stay.'...);
```

This shows that two users have written reviews for the same hotel.

Hotels has the following columns: hotel_id, price, rating, url

hotel_id and url are unique so I need to eliminate the duplicates and instert the information for each hotel only once.

I tried to do this but it didn't work:

```
INSERT INTO Hotels(hotel_id, price, rating, url)
SELECT DISTINCT hotel_id, price, rating, url
FROM HotelReviews;
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have unique constraints defined on those two columns, you can use `INSERT OR IGNORE`:

```
insert or ignore into hotels(hotel_id, price, rating, url)
select hotel_id,
    price,
    rating,
    url
from hotelreviews;
```

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
INSERT INTO Hotels(hotel_id, price, rating, url)
SELECT hotel_id, price, rating, url 
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT hotel_id, price, rating, url
  FROM HotelReviews
)
```

Comment: How is this helpful? What if there are two rows with same hotel_id and url with different values in other columns?